# yql rss reader - not consistant

Tags: rss, yql

in the last 3 days, im trying to get data from rss addresses via yql.
im browsing to this url:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from xml where url = 'http://rss.nana10.co.il/?s=160'&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&diagnostics=true

sometimes it works, and sometimes i get "Bad Request" (when i press ctrl + f5, i loads again)
BTW, it happends with every xml rss i try.

is there a problem with the YQL servers or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YQL is only working intermittently after 3 days of being like this. See http://downdetector.com/status/yahoo

Answer (score 0):

YQL have been with problems in the last few days.
There is nothing that can be done. Yahoo must fix the problem, as is from they side...

This is a duplicate from a issue post a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886679/6886121

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it is not a bug from Yahoo :
"html table is no longer supported. See https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/product-atos/yql/index.htm for YQL Terms of Use""

See :
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

So deprecated or not ?

Comment: i asked for an xml, not html table.