# YQL feed parsing troubles

Tags: yql

I use Yahoo YQL to parse the next feed: https://www.thiscomplexworld.com/tag/optimization-and-analytics/feed/.
The problem is that the parsing result changes randomly from time to time. Sometimes it returns status code 400, sometimes it parses this feed successfully with the same query: [2 results examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCEgT.png). (sorry for placing them on the same picture - I can't insert more that 2 links)

So the question is How to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We (users) can't do nothing. Is a Yahoo end problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886679/6886121

Comment: Thank you, DJPRMF.